# How do I stop chrome from auto completing search text in the search bar with previously searched text?

Tags: google-chrome, search, autocomplete

I can't figure out how to stop chrome from adding on words to things that i've typed before in the search bar. for example, i have searched for "navy beans nutritiondata.self" previously. Now whenever i start typing "navy bean"... it completes the thing I typed before, "navy beans nutritiondata.self", so I have to press back space in order to just search for "navy beans". I already turned off "use a prediction service to autocomplete text in the search bar, which was found under settings/advanced/privacy. Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at the related questions in the "Related" list (on the right)?

Comment: I just did. I saw a similar topic, but i don't think it was actually resolved, and they are trying to do something a bit different than me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue but the Chromium team has always refused to provide a way to disable the inline autocomplete “feature”:

> "the code and UX complexity of this is nontrivial because inline
>   autocompletion is the central design feature around which all other
>   omnibox decisions are based."
>   https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667922#c8

I encourage you to create a report at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list (click the "New Issue" button near the logo) to ask for that feature.

Maybe if enough people do that, they'll consider providing that option.